# How do I get a link to auto fill an option on a form when clicked?

Tags: php

Sorry for the confusing title, I'm not sure how to word it. So, I have a page where you select different people that you would like to contact. When you click on their photo, it takes you to a contact page with a form to fill out. I want the "Email Address" input to auto fill based on what link they clicked. So, for example, if you click on John Smith, it will take you to the contact page, where johnsmith@gmail.com will already be filled in for the email portion. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide us with some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a parameter to your link href like so

```
 <a href='somepage.php?email=johnsmith@gmail.com'>John Smith</a>
```

Then on your php page use the $_GET super global to set the value of the input

```
 <input type='text' name='emailTo' value='<?= isset($_GET["email"])?$_GET["email"]:"") ?>'/>
```

if you don't want the email address to appear in the link then you can get at the email address via a map

```
<?php
   $emailMap = array("John Smith"=>"johnsmith@gmail.com",
                     "Glenn Quagmire"=>"glenn@giggity.com");

   <input type='text' name='emailTo' value='<?= isset($emailMap[$_GET["email"]])?$emailMap[$_GET["email"]]:"") ?>'/>
```

and for your link it would be

```
   <a href='somepage.php?email=John+Smith'>John Smith</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have all of the links go to the same contact page, but pass the email via GET.

So for example you have the following links:

```
<a href="contact.php?email=johnsmith@gmail.com">Image of John Smith</a>

<a href="contact.php?email=janesmith@gmail.com">Image of Jane Smith</a>
```

And then in `contact.php` you can do something like:

```
<input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $_GET['email']; ?>"/>
```

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. You can accept an answer by clicking on the tick beside it. Of course, we all gave basically the same answer at the same time, and the fact that @Orangepill remembered to check if the GET variable had been passed using `isset()`, means his answer is technically slightly better

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to have your images link to something like

```
contact.php?email=john.doe@email.com
```

If you then make sure that the email field inside the form on your contact page has that same name `email`, the browser should automatically fill in that field for you. No php required.

You could also do a check in the `contact.php` page to see if the email variable was set, and then set the field value based on that. That would look something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['email']) {
   echo '<input name="email" value="' . $_GET['email'] . '" />';
}
```

I think you should be fine with the first solution however in most modern browsers.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'll give the first one a try since we try to cross browser check all the way down to ie7.